# Why can't I get the sub-collection items in firebase in react in 2022

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i've been researching about how do i get the subcollection of firebase documents. Basically its `.get()` but its not working now in 2022 ***I THINK***. I have the code in below...

Let say this one I will create a subcollection path with the collections.

```
await setDoc(doc(db,list2[i],`${currentUser?.email}-${uid}`,`single_item`,`image`),{
    creator:username,name:name,img:downloadURL,email:currentUser?.email
})

await setDoc(doc(db,list2[i],`${currentUser?.email}-${uid}`,`group_item`,`images`),{
    creator:username,name:name,img:downloadURL,email:currentUser?.email
})
```

Now i'm getting all the items of firebase documents with these...

```
export const owneritemsRef = collection(db,'owner_items')
export const singleItemsRef = collection(db,'owner_items/single_item/image')
export const groupItemsRef = collection(db,'owner_items','group_item',`images`)
```

Now when I tried to read it in my react file...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(singleItemsRef)
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(singleItemsRef,snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot)
      setSearchFilter(snapshot.docs.map((doc,idx) => {
        console.log(doc.data())
        return {
          ...doc.data(),
            name:doc.data().name
          }
      }))
      setSearchList(snapshot.docs.map((doc,idx) => {
        console.log(doc)
        return {
          ...doc.data(),
          name:doc.data().name
        }
      }))
    })
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  },[])
```

It doesn't show anything...like it is completely null.. but I can see the `pathsegments of singleRef`... How do I get those documents please? The diagram is like this

```
owner-items -> (single/group) -> image/s -> { document items }
```

Comment: do let me know if my recommendations in answer below were helpful.

Comment: nah I don't think i understand hahahaha without samples..

Comment: I have added the code sample below,please check and let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 1):

A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID and the subcollections live under a specific document. To access the subcollection you'll need to specify that particular ID in the path reference.
Using [Collection Group Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) might be the easiest way to fetch all documents from collections with the same name which are passed in the `collectionGroup()` method.
You need to use `collection()` to get a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) instead of `doc()` which returns a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference).

Also check these similar examples for [Get Subcollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47634907/firestore-get-subcollection-of-document-found-with-where) and [fetching subcollection documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481627/fetching-documents-in-a-subcollection-of-a-cloud-firestore-database-does-not-ret).

**UPDATE**

If you need to get that specific nested subcollection you could try something similar to below

```
db.collectionGroup("orders").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  console.log(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => ({id: d.id, ...d.data()})))
})
```